# Using lodash .groupBy. How to group object inside an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm using lodash's _.groupBy to come up with the following data:

```
{
   "Generic Drugs":[
                      {
                          itemDes: "Dulcolax",
                          itemGeneric: "Bisacodyl",
                          price: '10'
                      },
                      {
                          itemDes: "Celine",
                          itemGeneric: "Ascorbic Acid",
                          price: '10'
                      },
                          {
                          itemDes: "Vitamic C",
                          itemGeneric: "Ascorbic Acid",
                          price: '10'
                      }
                   ],
  "None-generic Drugs" : [
                           {
                             itemDes: "test 1",
                             itemGeneric: "",
                             price: '10'
                           },
                           {
                             itemDes: "test 2",
                             itemGeneric: "",
                             price: '10'
                           }                                 
                   ]
}
```

I wanted to group the objects in Generic Drugs object by the property itemGeneric to come up an output like this:

```
{
   "Generic Drugs":[
                      "Ascorbic Acid" : [  
                                          { itemDes: "Celine" }, 
                                          { itemDesc: "Vitamin C" }
                                        ],
                      "Bisacodyl" : [
                                       { itemDes: "Dolculax" } 
                                    ]
  "None-generic Drugs" : [
                           {
                             itemDes: "test 1",
                             itemGeneric: "",
                             price: '10'
                           },
                           {
                             itemDes: "test 2",
                             itemGeneric: "",
                             price: '10'
                           }                                 
                   ]
}
```

Please somebody help me with this problem. Thanks for the answers. :)

Comment: Where's your code you used to generate the former object in the question?

Comment: check your output data, its not validate

Comment: I have this data from may db:


Generic Drugs | Dulcolax            |  Bisacodyl
----------------------------------------------
Generic Drugs | Vitamin C           |  Ascorbic Acid
-----------------------------------------------------
Generic Drugs | Celine                |  Ascorbic Acid
-------------------------------------------------------
Non-generic Drugs | test 2           | 
-------------------------------------------------------
Non-generic Drugs | Alaxan FR   | 



used this code to come up with the first object
_.groupBy(response.rs ,'revDescription');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.mapValues()` on the grouped data, and group each value by the 'itemGeneric':

```
_.mapValues(grouped, function(group, key) {
      return key === 'Generic Drugs' ? _.groupBy(group, 'itemGeneric') : group;
});
```

```js
var grouped = {
  "Generic Drugs": [{
    itemDes: "Dulcolax",
    itemGeneric: "Bisacodyl",
    price: '10'
  }, {
    itemDes: "Celine",
    itemGeneric: "Ascorbic Acid",
    price: '10'
  }, {
    itemDes: "Vitamic C",
    itemGeneric: "Ascorbic Acid",
    price: '10'
  }],
  "None-generic Drugs": [{
    itemDes: "test 1",
    itemGeneric: "",
    price: '10'
  }, {
    itemDes: "test 2",
    itemGeneric: "",
    price: '10'
  }]
};

var result = _.mapValues(grouped, function(group, key) {
      return key === 'Generic Drugs' ? _.groupBy(group, 'itemGeneric') : group;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If the original data item is something like this:

```
  {
      type: "Generic Drugs",
      itemDes: "Dulcolax",
      itemGeneric: "Bisacodyl",
      price: '10'
  }
```

You can do:

```
_(originalData).groupBy('type').mapValues(grouped, function(group, key) {
    return key === 'Generic Drugs' ? _.groupBy(group, 'itemGeneric') : group;
});
```

Comment: You're welcome :) I've edited the answer a bit (`if` to trinary), but the logic stays the same.